# How to sort all my document on MailDate without adding a dummy Field foo with value 1

Tags: c#, sorting, lucene.net

I have used google a lot for some example that I could use but haven't find any
that is similar to my problem. 
This is a complete Console example that works because I have added a dummy Field Foo to value 1 just to make all my document to be sorted.
I don't want to have to add a dummy foo Field
I just want to be able to sort all my documents so the newest entry according to MailDate come first when I read
So I add in this order 20160202121314, 20160222151024, 20160226162344
but when I read I want the reverse order like 
20160226162344, 20160222151024, 20160202121314

```
Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo
  (Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\luceneIndex"));

Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);

var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, 
   IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);

var doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("MailDate", "20160202121314", Field.Store.YES, 
   Field.Index.ANALYZED));

doc.Add(new Field("OrgNo", "556769-6868", Field.Store.YES, 
   Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

doc.Add(new Field("Name", "The British Food Company AB", Field.Store.YES, 
   Field.Index.ANALYZED));

doc.Add(new Field("Foo", "1", Field.Store.YES, 
   Field.Index.ANALYZED));
writer.AddDocument(doc);

doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("MailDate", "20160222151024", Field.Store.YES, 
   Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("OrgNo", "556559-8033", Field.Store.YES, 
   Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("Name", "Gult Kort AB", Field.Store.YES, 
   Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("Foo", "1", Field.Store.YES, 
   Field.Index.ANALYZED));          
writer.AddDocument(doc);

doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("MailDate", "20160226162344", Field.Store.YES, 
   Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("OrgNo", "000000-0000", Field.Store.YES, 
   Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("Name", "Master", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("Foo", "1", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
writer.AddDocument(doc);
writer.Dispose();

// Find all docs whose Foo contains 1, ordered by MailDate
var query = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "Foo", new 
   StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29)).Parse("1");
var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);
try
{
    var sort = new Sort(new SortField("MailDate", SortField.LONG, true));
    var results = searcher.Search(query, null, 1000, sort);
    foreach (var hit in results.ScoreDocs)
    {
        Document document = searcher.Doc(hit.Doc);
        Console.WriteLine("\tFound match: {0}", document.Get("MailDate"));
    }
}
```

//Tony

Answer (score 0):

This will work to sort

```
   writer.Dispose();

   var numRangeQuery = NumericRangeQuery.NewLongRange("MailDate", 0L, 
      long.MaxValue, true, true);

   var searcher = new IndexSearcher(luceneIndexDirectory, true);

   var sort = new Sort(new SortField("MailDate", SortField.LONG, true));

   var results = searcher.Search(numRangeQuery, null, 50, sort);

   searcher.Search(numRangeQuery, null, 50, sort);
```

The sorted data is in results.ScoreDocs.
       //Tony

//Tony